# How to display multi nested array of objects in html using angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Question: I have a JSON object which has random levels of nesting in it.
I want to parse the JSON array in HTML using ngFor.
I have used ngFor previously, but as we can have the different number of children for any of the objects, I am unable to come up with a solution for this. I am having difficulty figuring out a general way to produce HTML page dynamically.

The JSON:

```
    [
        {
            name: a,
            children: [
            ]
        },

        {
            name: b,
            children: [
                {
                    name: b1,
                    children: [
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: b2,
                    children: [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: c,
            children: [
                {
                    name: c1,
                    children: [
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: c2,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: cc2,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: ccc2,
                                    children: [
                                    ]
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My HTML Template:

[image]

```
<div class="tree well">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Home Page</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
      <ul>

        <li>
          <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Transport </span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
          <ul >
            <!--<li>
              <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Transport Page</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
            </li>-->
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Transport </span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Transport Page</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

          <ul>
            <li>
              <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
            </li>

            <li>

              <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
              <ul>
                <li>

                  <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>

                      <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>

                      <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span> <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hint: [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: As @MarcinOrlowski mentioned, you can use recursion if you are building your own directive. I once used [Angular Tree component](https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example) and it's pretty good

Comment: Thanks @MarcinOrlowski. The keyword Recursion has shown me the direction.

Comment: Thanks @SahanSerasinghe. I will surely look into the suggestion.